# Google App Engine Eclipse Plugin Classpath used to compile JSPs

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsp, google-app-engine

I'm using the Google Cloud Tools appengine-maven-plugin (V 1.1.0-beta) to build and deploy a WAR to the google app engine (standard) from Eclipse (Neon.2 Release 4.6.2) on OS X under Java version: 1.7.0_80. The app includes JSPs that reference java classes using the following import directive:

```
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService"%>
<%@ page import="com.semplar.session.UserSession"%>
```

All was working well and I could successfully deploy my app to Google using the "Deploy to App Engine Std...". All JSPs compiled, and the app ran successfully.

So why am I posting? In preparation to break my app into modules/services, I moved all the core code into its own Eclipse project and packaged it into a jar. The class UserSession was moved into the new project.

When I try to deploy my app now, I get the following error:

```
.../settings_jsp.java:8: error: package com.semplar.session does not exist
import com.semplar.session.UserSession;
```

My local class was not resolved. Note that the Google-provided BlobstoreService class was resolved.

Note that when I build my application outside of Eclipse with Maven, the app builds successfully and can be deployed.

I want to be able to build and deploy my app from inside Eclipse (via "Deploy to App Engine Std..."). Can anyone tell me how to add jar files to the class path directive to the appropriate place so I can build and deploy from inside Eclipse?

Thanks,

-- Dave

Comment: Do you see the project containing the `com.semplar.session.UserSession` class as a dependency to the project that contains `settings,jsp` in the Eclipse Project Explorer/Package Explorer?

Comment: András: Yes, it's one of the Maven dependencies included in the project.

Comment: Can you check if the jar (possibly as part of the Maven dependencies) is added to the Deployment Descriptor (right click on the project/Properties/Deployment Descriptor) of the WAR project?